# Eclipse: Debugging... then seems to stop in a while loop, without debugging the following codes, why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, while-loop

my friends ,i have to admit that the question is a little long, but to make you more clear of the question, i pasted the codes here, its some android codes. you neednt look at it carefully, its only a reference. for some functions of the codes doesnt work, i began to debug( using Eclipse). everything is ok before the `while` loop (i have marked it in the code), when enter the while loop, something magic that happens:

1. the first loop, after executing the code `while((msg  = d.readLine()) != null)`, the value of `msg` variable is blank, maybe its not `null`, because you will soon enter the second loop right now.
2. the second loop, after executing the code `while((msg  = d.readLine()) != null)`, the value of `msg` variable is `touchasd not found`, yes, its what i really want
3. the third loop, after executing the code `while((msg  = d.readLine()) != null)`, the small arrow which indicates the current line of code disappeared! i cannot find it anywhere! and the ***step over*** button is grey! i even cannot click it to continue the debug! just as the debugging is over! but i have some codes below that dont execute at all !   nothing in `logcat`. it seems that eclipse think it is ok, without any error occurred.

   ```
       try {
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
       DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
       TextView suCommandMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.suCommandMessage);
       BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
       outputStream.writeBytes("touchasd /m\n");
       String sb = "";
       String msg = "";

       /////////////////////////////////////HERE/////////////////////////////////////

       while((msg  = d.readLine()) != null) {
           sb = sb + msg;
       }

       /////////////////////////////////////HERE/////////////////////////////////////

       suCommandMessage.setText(sb);
       outputStream.writeBytes("exit \n");
       p.waitFor();
       } catch(IOException e) {
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                          .setTitle("Exception")
                          .setMessage("IOException: " + e)
                          .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                          .show();
       } catch(InterruptedException e) {
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
              .setTitle("Exception")
              .setMessage("InterruptedException: " + e)
              .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
              .show();
       }
   ```

   }

[image: i make a screenshot when i cannot continue the debugging]

Comment: And when i tried to run the program in my android cellphone, the program didnt respond for a long time, i have to close it forcely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **handle the exceptions**, for starter - at least use `e.printStackTrace()` in the exception blocks.

It might be that an exception was thrown and it braught you out of the loop, skipping the marked while loop and the lines:

```
suCommandMessage.setText(sb);
outputStream.writeBytes("exit \n");
p.waitFor();
```

**EDIT: Not related**, but still important:

You might want to avoid using `operator+` on strings in loops. It creates a lot of objects [each `+` creates a new object]. You might want to user a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead, and after you are done building your string - only then convert it back to string,

Comment: thx, but i really have the catch clause, IMO it is not important, so i omitted it in the code, you can look at the picture that i displayed above. im sorry, just to make the code more clearly, i have edited the code above to add the catch clause to avoid misunderstanding. and thanks for the note "StringBuilder". Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

99% of the times that you have an empty catch clause, you have a bug.

In very rare occasions, you might actually want that (I would advice adding a simple comment explaining why the clause is empty), in all other cases... you're simply masking behavior, and you'll spend countless hours debugging things you would notice right ahead if you were throwing/printing the exception.

That said, add e.printStackTrace(); at least to your catch clauses.

Also, you can add a breakpoint to Eclipse that stops execution when an exception is thrown (parametized for both caught and uncaught exceptions).

Comment: thx, but i really have the catch clause, IMO it is not important, so i omitted it in the code, you can look at the picture that i displayed above. im sorry, just to make the code more clearly, i have edited the code above  to add the catch clause to avoid misunderstanding. Do you have any other idea? :)